# How can I add styles to all the children of an element

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

For example how could I implement the `addStyles` function in this snippet

```
const addStyles = // ...
const Element = ({ children }) => (
    <div>{children.map(addStyles)}</div>
);
```

thanks

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried extracting the className, wrapping my components, targeting children with css ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`React.Children.map`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#react.children.map) function provided from facebook.

> Invokes a function on every immediate child contained within children with this set to thisArg. If children is a keyed fragment or array it will be traversed: the function will never be passed the container objects. If children is null or undefined, returns null or undefined rather than an array.

Then return a clone of each child with an appropriate style like so using [`React.cloneElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). This will shallowly merge any property provided in the object in the second argument. Those you could use it to override current styles of the children.  You could potentially provide `{ className: "newClassName" }` as a second argument if you prefer.

```
const StylishComponent = ({ children }) => {
    const iLikeBlueStyles = { color: "blue" };

    const clones = React.Children.map(children, child => {
        return React.cloneElement(child, { style: iLikeBlueStyles });
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {clones}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I've been using to iterate over the children, but it still doesn't help me implement the `addStyles` functionality

Comment: ill add a sample snippet to the answer soon

Comment: Let me know if this helps!

Comment: make sure to call this before clone `React.isValidElement(child) && React.cloneElement(child, { style: styles })`